# Navigation bar back button image align with screen edge

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Does anyone know how I can move a back button image to the edge of the screen?

This is what it looks like right now:

[image: how it looks like right now]

and this is how I want it to look:

[image: how I want it to be]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change its insets:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -12, bottom: 0, right: 12)
```

and find values to move it right to the edge.

Comment: I've tried this and self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.imageInsets too, non of it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you add custom view as a button and add as `leftBarButtonItem` it always takes default x (frame's start position) position for that view as defined for navigation bar item. You can add something like this to get your desired output:

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addBackButton()
    }
    

    func addBackButton() {
        
        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)))
   
        let btnBack = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -25, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45))
        btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named: "dark_ic_back.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        btnBack.tintColor = .black
        btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        containerView.addSubview(btnBack)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containerView)
    }
    
    @objc func backAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
       self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: screenshot]